# "Падают" файлы после обновления страницы со сценарием

Tags: php

Сценарий составляет таблицу из 6 картинок 2х3 и каждой картинке привязывает ссылку на какой либо документ. Выборка файлов происходит в html, сценарий копирует выбранные файлы в нужные папки и строит из них таблицу. 
Всё казалось бы работает, но если перейти по одной ссылке и возвратиться на предыдущую страницу, после обновления этой страницы файлы перезаписываются как пустые, хотя держат оригинальные названия. Хочется узнать, почему?
Код конечно может относится к разряду "говнокода"

---

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/site_krj/script.php">
<tr>
   <td>Выберите 1 файл</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="myfile[0]"></td>
   <td>Выберите 1 изображение</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="picture[0]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Выберите 2 файл</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="myfile[1]"></td>
   <td>Выберите 2 изображение</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="picture[1]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Выберите 3 файл</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="myfile[2]"></td>
   <td>Выберите 3 изображение</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="picture[2]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Выберите 4 файл</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="myfile[3]"></td>
   <td>Выберите 4 изображение</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="picture[3]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Выберите 5 файл</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="myfile[4]"></td>
   <td>Выберите 5 изображение</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="picture[4]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Выберите 6 файл</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="myfile[5]"> </td>
   <td>Выберите 6 изображение</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="picture[5]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td colspan="5"><center><input type="submit" value="Go to Script"></center></td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

> php

```
<?php
$temp_mass_doc=$_FILES['myfile'];
$temp_mass_pic=$_FILES['picture'];

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($temp_mass_pic);
print_r($temp_mass_doc);
echo "</pre>";*/

function copy_pic($temp_mass_pic, $mass_adress_pic)  //копирование изображений
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($temp_mass_pic['name']); $i++)
    {
        $adress_copy="pic/".$temp_mass_pic['name'][$i];
        $adress_precopy=$temp_mass_pic['tmp_name'][$i];

            $mass_adress_pic[$i]=$adress_copy;

        if(!move_uploaded_file ($adress_precopy, $adress_copy))
        {echo "Файл не скопирован";}
    }
    return $mass_adress_pic;
}

function copy_doc($temp_mass_doc, $mass_adress_doc)  //копирование htmk-документов
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($temp_mass_doc['name']); $i++)
    {
        $adress_copy="document/".$temp_mass_doc['name'][$i];
        $adress_precopy=$temp_mass_doc['tmp_name'][$i];

            $mass_adress_doc[$i]=$adress_copy;

        if(!move_uploaded_file ($adress_precopy, $adress_copy))
        {echo "Файл не скопирован";}
    }
    return $mass_adress_doc;
}

$mass_adress_pic=array();
$mass_adress_doc=array();

if(file_exists('pic')) {   //проверяем на наличие папки pic
   $mass_adress_pic=copy_pic($temp_mass_pic, $mass_adress_pic);
}
else {  //если отсутствует, создаем
    if(mkdir("pic"))
    {
        $mass_adress_pic=copy_pic($temp_mass_pic, $mass_adress_pic);
    }
    else {echo "Папка не создана, копирование невозможно";}
}

if(file_exists('document')) {  //проверяем на наличие папки document
    $mass_adress_doc=copy_doc($temp_mass_doc, $mass_adress_doc);
}
else {   //если отсутствует, создаем
    if(mkdir("document"))
    {
        $mass_adress_doc=copy_doc($temp_mass_doc, $mass_adress_doc);
    }
    else {echo "Папка не создана, копирование невозможно";}
}

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($mass_adress_pic);
print_r($mass_adress_doc);
echo "</pre>";*/

$number_mass=0;
echo '<html><head><title></title></head><body><center><table border="0" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" >';

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=0; $j<2; $j++)
    {
        echo '<td><a href="'.$mass_adress_doc[$number_mass].'"><img src="'.$mass_adress_pic[$number_mass].'"></a></td>';
        $number_mass++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></center></body></html>"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Но ведь при первом выборе файлы не являются пустыми, это наглядно видно
При первом выполнении скрипта и повторной обновлении страницы таблица строится правильно, не один файл не падает, **но стоит перейти по ссылке, вернуться назад и обновить страницу**, только в этот момент файлы занулются

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй проверять выбранный файл на пустоту.